# po Swift String "unresolved identifier"

Tags: swift, lldb

I am having trouble debugging Swift Strings

```
func stringTest() {

    let test1:String =   "test1";
    let test2:NSString = "test2";

    // <-- Breakpoint here

    println(test1);
    println(test2);
}
```

If I set a breakpoint after these lines and try and print test1 I get the following error:

```
po test1
error: <REPL>:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'test1'
test1
^
```

But I am able to print test2 successfully:

```
po test2
test2
```

Comment: Have you tried printing them directly in your code, not from the debugger? This should work.

Comment: Beta software. Debug console for swift is useless at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I am able to print both directly from code, it is just using the debugger that I get the error.

Comment: (Maybe it's the semicolons? Seriously; that's the only difference between your code and mine, that works...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in the debug information output.  You can check this by grabbing the PC, for instance from `register read pc`, and then doing:

```
(lldb) image lookup -va <PC VALUE>
```

That will print a bunch of stuff, but the last entries will be all the variables currently visible to the debugger, and where they live (in registers or memory.)  If you don't see the variable there, then the debug information must have told lldb that the variable is not currently live.

If you can reproduce this in some example code you can make available, please file a bug with bug reporter.apple.com.

Comment: I tried your image lookup instruction and I can see my variables :  Variable: id = {0x1600000179}, name = "visibleRect", type = "CoreGraphics.CGRect", location =  DW_OP_piece(0x8) DW_OP_constu(0x0)  v9 DW_OP_piece(0x8) v10 DW_OP_piece(0x8), decl = QuestionListLayoutHandler.swift:22 even though the po doesn't work : error: <EXPR>:2:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'visibleRect'
Any idea why ? (XCode 8.2) I have this nearly on all my code since a few days.

Answer (score 17):

It is a bug of Beta. Xcode6-Beta5 has still this bug.
You can only get debug info for swift's variables, but can't get it for swift's constants.
Temporarily you can change **let test1** to **var test1** and you will got debug info.
Hope this will be fixed in release version. Good Luck in debugging ;)

EDIT:
Unfortunately, the same issue is still happening in first release of Xcode Version 6.0.1 (6A317)

```
let test1:String  -> debug info is unavailable
var test1:String  -> debug info is available
```

EDIT2:
Yes, confirmed. It is fixed also for iOS apps in the latest Xcode 6.1 under OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Xcode 6.1 (6A1042b); at least in OS X apps, possibly still a bug with iOS apps.

Comment: Xcode 6.1 fixes it for iOS apps as well. (My question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189424/how-to-view-value-of-swift-let-constant-in-xcode-6-debugger) came from an iOS app.)

Comment: Broken again in 6.3 Beta 1, fixed again in 6.3 Beta 2

Comment: Xcode 6.3.2 still has such issues from time to time.

Comment: Xcode 6.4 also. Mostly on class-vars. Any of: 'p self.myVar', 'p myVar', 'po myVar'... all fail

Comment: 2 Months later, still an issue in Xcode 8.2.1. Its embarassing.