# How to view value of Swift "let" constant in Xcode 6 debugger

Tags: swift, xcode6, lldb

When I'm stopped in the debugger in Xcode 6, how can I view the value of a local Swift constant declared with `let`?

If I create a *brand new Swift project* in Xcode 6 and add the following two lines to `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in the app delegate:

```
let someConstant = 5
var someVariable = 6
```

…then run the app and break immediately after these lines, this is what I see in the variables view of the debugger:

[image: screenshot of variables view; someVariable shows 6 and someConstant is listed twice without showing its value]

Why does the variable display its value, while the constant does not? (And why is the constant listed twice?)

If, in the LLDB console, I try `p`, `po`, or `fr v` on `someConstant` (*all* of which correctly display the value of `someVariable`), I get the following:

[image: screenshot of console; p and po both result in a "use of unresolved identifier" error and fr v displays someConstant as "empty constant data"]

I'm aware that I can print the value in the debugger by using `println` in my source code, but I'd really rather not have to have the foresight to do that every time I simply want to inspect a value I've declared as a constant. (Even running `expr println(someConstant)` in the LLDB console produced the same "unresolved identifier" error as `p` and `po`.)

This should be easy. What am I missing?

Comment: See the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309005/po-swift-string-unresolved-identifier Apparent;y this is a recognized bug.

Comment: Do check - SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL http://stackoverflow.com/a/28518621/1294448

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in Xcode which I can confirm was fixed in Xcode 6.1. (Thanks, Steve Rosenberg.)

This is what I get now, as expected:

[image: screenshot of console; p, po, and fr v now all display the value of someConstant in some way or another]

The constant is now displayed correctly in the variables view as well, and is no longer listed twice:

[image: screenshot of variables view; someVariable shows 6 and someConstant shows 5]

Comment: I have the same issue, but even with variables... no optimisation and release mode ! Can't understand what's happening !