# Problems with local CocoaPods and Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I try to integrate a local Swift CocoaPod into a Swift Project, but it will not work :(

I simply created a Swift project with just one class and one function.
This should be the CocoaPod.
Here is the Podspecs:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name          = "CocoaPodTest"
    s.module_name   = "CocoaPodTest"
    s.version       = "0.1"
    s.license       = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
    s.author        = { "Stefan Sturm" => "stefan@urkman.de" }
    s.source_files  = "src/*.swift"
    s.requires_arc  = true
    s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
end
```

And then I created another simple App, that should use the pod. 
Here is the Podfile:

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire'

# local pods
pod 'CocoaPodTest', :path => '../CocoaPodTest'
```

Now I try to access the class included using the pod:

Import the Module:

```
import CocoaPodTest
```

Then call the class and function:

```
Foo.doIt()
```

But here I get this error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'Foo'
```

I made a github project to show this error:[github](https://github.com/Urkman/cocoapod-test)

Thanks for your Help :)

Urkman

Comment: may be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497533/po-gives-error-expr11-error-use-of-unresolved-identifier) helps you

Comment: Is your class Foo public?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Few points regarding `Foo.doIt()` (as in your [repo at git hub](https://github.com/Urkman/cocoapod-test/blob/master/CocoaPodTest/src/Foo.swift))

1. Your class is not public
2. Your method is not public
3. Your method is not class level method

Solve all these you are good to go

```
public class Foo {
    public class func doIt()
    {
        println("do it !!!")
    }
}
```

Comment: I now it had to be that simple :)