# How to call nested Swift function in Xcode Debugger?

Tags: xcode, swift, debugging, nested-function

In Xcode Debugger, how can I call a function inside of a function?

Code (`errorMessage` is an instance method, and `firstName` & `lastName` are properties of `self`.)

```
func errorMessage() -> String? {
    func isValidName(name: String) -> Bool {
        return 1...50 ~= name.characters.count
    }

    var nameType: String?
    if !isValidName(firstName) {
        nameType = "First"
    } else if !isValidName(lastName) {
        nameType = "Last"
    }

    if let messagePrefix = nameType {
        return "\(messagePrefix) name must be between 1 & 50 characters."
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Debugger (while stopped at the first if statement above)

```
(lldb) p isValidName("Matt")
error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'isValidName'
isValidName("Matt")
^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: the problem looks very much fixed in this discussion here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497533/po-gives-error-expr11-error-use-of-unresolved-identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug.  There's already a report of it, but if you want to file another at http://bugreporter.apple.com we'll dup it to the original and you'll get notified when the original is resolved.

Comment: Ah, no, that's your bug...  No need to file another...  Not fixed yet...  Nothing happened here...