# xcode 8 Debugger 'Could not resolve type'

Tags: ios, debugging, xcode8

In Xcode 8, When any break point is hit, and I try to print any object in the Xcode debugger, it always prints **"Could not resolve type"**. I have searched enough on the internet. I have checked if EditScheme->Run->Info->BuildConfiguration is set to 'Debug'. Build setting->Optimisation level is set to 'None'. But no clues on why this happens. Could anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance.

[image: Xcode8 Debugger]

Comment: Is this an old-ish project?

Comment: No. This project is created using Xcode8

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper did you solve this issue?

Comment: @ Reiner Melian No not yet. Still I have this issue.

Comment: refer this ['Could not solve type' - resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45058945/4960875) You may find your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue with a pure swift framework that doesn't have any bridging headers but non the less had `SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER` set to `YES`

It is described in more detail at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51186560/385307

After changing the setting to `NO` debugging works again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a Swift project which included an Obj-C framework. I had imported the framework in my Swift project using

```
import Obj-C-Framework
```

Additionally, I had also created a Bridging-Header file in the Swift project and included the Obj-C-Framework header using

```
#include <Obj-C-Framework/Obj-C-Framework.h>
```

This was causing the Xcode debugger to always show *'could not resolve type'* when printing objects in breakpoints. Removing the #include in the Bridging-Header fixed the issue and objects print correctly in breakpoints.

TL;DR If your swift project uses an Obj-C framework make sure that the framework headers are **not** included in your Swift project's bridging header.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and it had been solved.My project is a Mixed project with both OC and Swift. I found that some .h file import in my Bridging Header file that caused the problem. Definitely, an enum declared in the .h file cause the problem, like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger,BadgeAlignment) {
    AlignmentCenter,
    AlignmentLeft,
    AlignmentRight,
};
```

If i comment the code, everything goes alright.

And I just add a prefix to each element of the enum and the problem is solved for me.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger,BadgeAlignment) {
    BadgeAlignmentCenter,
    BadgeAlignmentLeft,
    BadgeAlignmentRight,
};
```

I just thinking if there is a conflict with some enum in Swift when convert the .h to Swift.

I'm still confused...